# Virtualbox won't work with kernel 3.16.0-34; can't use any newer kernel

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I'm using 3.16.0-34 kernel version on Ubuntu 15.10. With any newer kernel version I get more and more problems. With first post-3.16 versions, the fan would go to full speed non-stop after waking from suspend, wheres with the 4.2 the system can't even recognize my WiFi adapter (it appears as it if it was mechanically disabled with the laptop switch, the blue wifi light is off and it can't be turned on by pressing it; I switch back to 3.16 and everything works perfectly)... This means that using a newer kernel is out of the question.

So, what's the problem? When I install Virtualbox through `apt-get install virtualbox` and then run it, I get this:

```
The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
     Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
     headers, most likely linux-headers-generic
```

`virtualbox-dkms` is installed. Virtualbox does start, but when I choose to start one of the systems, I get an error:

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please install virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module by executing

'modprobe vboxdrv'

as root. If it is available in your distribution, you should install the DKMS package first. This package keeps track of Linux kernel changes and recompiles the vboxdrv kernel module if necessary.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.
```

Running `modprobe vboxdrv` gives me `modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found.`

If I try to install the latest Virtualbox from the package downloaded from virtualbox.org, I get the following:

```
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (3.16.0-34-generic) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

           sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

When I run `sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup`, I get this:

```
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules ...failed!
  (Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong)
```

All there is in the log is this:

```
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
```

I googled the error and the suggestions are to run `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`, but that just tells me that the package "linux-headers-3.16.0-34-generic" is not available but is required by another package and that this means that the package is either missing, outdated or available only from another source...

That's where Google doesn't help anymore. What the hell do I do to get Virtualbox to work?!

Comment: What happens when you run 'sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic'?

Comment: @Brian It asks me whether to install the following additional packages: `linux-headers-4.2.0-34 linux-headers-4.2.0-34-generic` and the following new packages `linux-headers-4.2.0-34 linux-headers-4.2.0-34-generic linux-headers-generic`. EDIT: One of the errors says to "Specify KERN_DIR=<directory>". Is there a way to do this, i.e. to point it to the 3.16 kernel packages?

Comment: What's your output of 'uname -a'?

Comment: I'm guessing the current kernel you're running is obsolete, and it's no longer in the repo.

Comment: @Brian, well, 3.16.0-34-generic. I'm assuming that is the problem, but I'm wondering if there's any way to circumvent it. However, the only reason I'm trying to get Virtualbox to work is to be able to use my printer from within Ubuntu, as there are no linux drivers for it. I can get Virtualbox to work properly with newer kernel, but I can't get the guest Windows to recognize the printer. Even though there are no linux drivers for my printer, Ubuntu does recognize it, Windows within Virtualbox doesn't. So, not to waste any more time trying to get VB to work on 3.16 -- is it even possible...

Comment: ...to get guest Windows to recognize my printer even though the printer has no drivers for Linux (considering, again, that Ubuntu does recognize the printer, but that's all it can do with it, and that the printer is fully functional on a non-VM Windows installation)? If that's not possible, than I don't need to waste my time on getting VB to work on 3.16...

Comment: I'm sorry for the "extended discussion", but I got the printer to work in VM on 4.2 (Guest Additions + Virtualbox extension pack + add yourself to vboxusers group = printer recognized in VM), which means I'm still interested in getting VB to work on 3.16.